# Youtube Data API - Agency use case, large volume of video uploads, API quota issues

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are building an application that manages video campaigns on DV 360. It includes uploading and changing a lot of YouTube videos on a daily basis.

We found that the YT Data API allows us to upload about 5 videos daily before we exhaust the API quota. We requested an extension via the public form. But there is no public information about the SLA for that form or how to get additional Dev support with the API. Which we will need, as our use case is different from the typical API user (apparently).

Has anybody gone through this process successfully and/or found a way to get Dev Support from Google for the YouTube Data API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are indeed very much pertinent.

I can state -- based on my experience monitoring the tags [youtube-data-api](/questions/tagged/youtube-data-api) and [youtube-api](/questions/tagged/youtube-api) for more than three years -- that there's no official info related to SLAs and Dev Support here on SO.

The YouTube Data API is officially a free of charge API. But that does not exclude the possibility of Google offering this API under different conditions to clients willing to pay for the services provided to them.

I'd recommend to address your issues directly to Google, either through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/), or through its [own support forum](https://support.google.com/youtube/).